# Secondary hover transition not working

Tags: html, css, hover

[TEMPLATE](http://jsfiddle.net/Anchorsify/91bamnjt/1/)

I'm trying to modify this template to allow it to, instead of having that white X transition over one 400x400 image, instead split it up into four different images separated by the lines, which then transition appropriately with the X as it flattens and then brings up the text field on hover.  I've done this, and gotten the multiple images and transition effect theoretically solved:

```
.topImage {
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}
.botImage {
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
}
.leftImageContainer {
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border: 0px solid black;
top: 0;
left: -200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.leftImage {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: green;
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari */
transform: rotate(45deg);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -83px;
}
.rightImageContainer {
position: absolute;
border: 0px solid black;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
top: 0;
right: -200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.rightImage {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: purple;
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari */
transform: rotate(45deg);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: -83px;
}
#xdiv:hover .leftImageContainer {
height: 0;
top: 200px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
#xdiv:hover .leftImage {
top: -200px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
#xdiv:hover .rightImageContainer {
height: 0;
top: 200px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
#xdiv:hover .rightImage {
top: -200px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Anchorsify/dhkujsh4/5/)

But for some reason, I can not get the hover transitions that go along with wrap1 and wrap2 to appear.  I'm not exactly sure if this is the best way to go about it, but I'm just as not sure about why the hover effect isn't showing, since it's z-index should place it on top on hover just like in the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.wrap1` was hidden from view because it was underneath (not behind) the 400x400 "X" image, so I moved it up 400px.

```
.wrap1 {
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    top: -400px; /*Move .wrap1 up into view*/

    height: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: height 1s 0.5s, margin-top 1s 0.5s;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```